# How can I find the source of a CSS property in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a website where the header logo looks good in the original language, but looks cropped in a different language. HTML and CSS should be the same in both, so there should be no difference, but when examining with Chrome Developer Tools, I see that, in the original language, the header logo has "116 x 20" as width and height, while in the other language it has "70 x 20".

So I try to trace the source of that "width" property, but it doesn't look like it's defined explicitly anywhere. In Chrome Developer Tools, the "Styles" tab doesn't have a "width" property, and in the "Computed" tab I see this:

[image: Screenshot]

"width" is greyed out. So how can I trace where this property is defined?

Comment: _Is_ it actually defined/explicitly set anywhere? Especially with an image, that could be the just the intrinsic dimensions here, I suppose? Are you _sure_ the image is the same in both versions?

Comment: Yes, I just checked - for an image embedded with just `<img src="...">` and no explicit width/height set, Chrome dev tools will show the width exactly this way. (As soon as width or height are set as HTML attributes, it will show them as from “element style”.)

Comment: Well, you were right! I looked again and it was a much more subtle problem: the image wasn't loading in the other language's version, because of a path problem. (What I don't understand is why Chrome was showing a cropped image then, instead of just a blank space).

Comment: if width is not defined on image, check `max-width` and parent width